# connections blocked to remote computer while no user logged on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-firewall

A have a bunch of computers, all in the same OU, that are not contactable over the LAN (no pinging, no c$, no computer management, no SCCM connection) while the computer is not being used.

The minute a user logs in, the computers are contactable over the LAN: I can ping,  get c$, do remote computer management, get SCCM connection

I have reviewed the gp results, and see nothing to suggest the cause of this behaviour.  Is there a GPO setting that could cause this behavior?  Is there a setting on the machine that could cause this behavior?

Comment: Could you please retype your question? I have no idea what you mean. Do you mean that you cannot login using mstsc?

Comment: @idarryl Do you have physical access to that computer? Alternatively, can you reproduce this problem on a VM?

Comment: Perhaps power saving is turning off the NICs? Does the computer become unreachable as soon as a user logs off or some time after?

Comment: @EliadTech I've moved a VM test computer into the same OU as the computers affected, and was unable to reproduce this problem, which removes GPOs from potential causes

Comment: @dartonw Perhaps.  I'll need to wait until tomorrow to test this.

Comment: @idarryl OK, so do you have physical access to one of these faulty machines?